# Batch scripting: find file and remove lines

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to batch scripting and could use some assistance.
I'm trying to write a batch script that will open a .txt file, remove the first 4 lines, and delete some other things leaving just some numbers. I need some help deleting the first four lines.

```
@echo off
title test1
start users_6042014.txt

for /f "skip=4 delims=*" %%a in (C:\users_6042014.txt) do (
echo %%a >>C:\newfiletest.txt    
)
xcopy C:\newfiletest.txt C:\users_6042014.txt /y
```

I thought this would delete the first lines and make a copy of the new file but it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell us what isn't "working" about the batch.

The `start users_6042014.txt` will open the file with the default editor (presumably notepad) which is probably not what you want to do. Try commenting this line out, or remove it completely.

Note that

```
echo %%a >>C:\newfiletest.txt
```

will append to any existing `C:\newfiletest.txt` an probably also append a space to the end of each line.

Try

```
(for /f "skip=4 delims=*" %%a in (C:\users_6042014.txt) do echo %%a)>C:\newfiletest.txt
```

to create the file anew.

Finally, `move` in place of `xcopy` would replace the existing file; `C:\newfiletest.txt` would no longer exist.

Comment: I tried that and it just copied the name of the file and made a blank file in my C: drive...It didn't remove the first four lines and copy the new file.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

This will ignore lines starting with `;` and blank lines.

```
@echo off
title test1

for /f "usebackq skip=4 delims=" %%a in ("C:\users_6042014.txt") do (
>>"C:\newfiletest.txt" echo %%a
)
move "C:\newfiletest.txt" "C:\users_6042014.txt"
```